# Issue of creating a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe by using for loop. It works but the output of the dataframe is not correct. Each cell of the Dataframe contain all data. May I know how can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime
from math import exp, sqrt
import pandas as pd


records = []

test = ['AAPL','AAL']

for i in test:

    stock_price = data.DataReader(test,
                           start='2021-01-01', 
                           end='2021-04-01', 
                           data_source='yahoo')['Adj Close'][-100:]

    stock_volume = data.DataReader(test,
                           start='2021-01-01', 
                           end='2021-04-01', 
                           data_source='yahoo')['Volume'][-100:]


    returns = stock_price.pct_change()
    ((1 + returns).cumprod() - 1)
    


    records.append({
                    'underlyingSymbol' : i,
                    'last_price' : stock_price.iloc[-1],
                    '15d_highest' : stock_price.iloc[-15:].max(),
                    '15d_lowest' : stock_price.iloc[-15:].min(),
                   })

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looping over symbols, you should change `data.DataReader(test...` to `data.DataReader(i...` (otherwise it reads data for both of them on every iteration):

```
for i in test:
    stock_price = data.DataReader(i,
                           start='2021-01-01', 
                           end='2021-04-01', 
                           data_source='yahoo')['Adj Close'][-100:]

    stock_volume = data.DataReader(i,
                           start='2021-01-01', 
                           end='2021-04-01', 
                           data_source='yahoo')['Volume'][-100:]
...
```

Output:

```
  underlyingSymbol  last_price  15d_highest  15d_lowest  15d_volume  \
0             AAPL  123.000000       125.57  119.900002  92403800.0   
1              AAL   23.860001        25.17   21.809999  93746800.0   

   30d_returns  15d_returns  7d_returns  volatility  
0    -0.047342     0.018057    0.024240    0.325800  
1     0.266432     0.030475    0.092192    0.571564
```

Comment: Sure, you're most welcome! If it helped, can you please accept the answer? Thanks!